# Case Approval - Time Limit, Then Send Email Reminder?

Tags: approval-process, email-alert, case

I am not finding any reference to this being a possibility (outside programming a Trigger, I assume).

Is it possible in SF to have an Approval process "time out" (they don't approve it disapprove it within 14 days) and cause a reminder email to be sent to those that approval is being waited upon from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no solution at this time (the one offered by @user988 mentions approving or rejecting the case which was not the request anyway).  Salesforce support has no solution either.  (sigh)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a workflow to give the user a reminder to approve the case (after a number of days) and then have the workflow approve or reject the case if it still hasn't been approved.

Comment: Really?  How do you fire a workflow based on an Approval being requested?